# uvm configure_phase is never called

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Hi I have a testbench environment where I have to do something every test in configuration phase. So I have decided to put in base_test as follows

```
class base_test extends uvm_test;
  ....

  task configure_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.configure_phase(phase);
    phase.raise_objection(phase);
    `uvm_info(get_name(), "Entered configure_phase", UVM_LOW)
    phase.drop_objection(phase);
  endtask
endclass

class actual_test extends base_test;
  ....
endclass
```

When I run a test that is extending from base_test, configure_phase is never called automatically when the flow goes through UVM phasing. Is there something extra I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If the `test` extended from `base_test` has a `configure_phase`, it needs to call `super.configure_phase(phase);`

---

You really need to show a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), like this below which works for me.

```
import uvm_pkg::*;
`include "uvm_macros.svh"

class base_test extends uvm_test;
function new(string name="",uvm_component parent);
  super.new(name,parent);
endfunction
`uvm_component_utils(base_test)
  task configure_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.configure_phase(phase);
    `uvm_info(get_name(), "Entered configure_phase", UVM_LOW)
  endtask
endclass

class actual_test extends base_test;
function new(string name="",uvm_component parent);
  super.new(name,parent);
endfunction
`uvm_component_utils(actual_test)
endclass
module top;
  initial run_test("actual_test");
endmodule
```

BTW, you should not raise and drop an objection without some delay between them, or don't do it altogether.

Comment: There is no configure_phase defined in the test

Comment: Still not enough. The code I just posted works for me

Comment: Could be an older version of UVM without runtime phases.

Comment: Only the UVM early adopter (early alpha :)) release in 2011 did not have those phases.